# Difference between 2 types of C #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Can someone explain me the difference between the following defines:

```
#define ADDR_VAL(x) (*((volatile unsigned long *)(x)))
```

and

```
#define ADDR_VAL(x) (*((volatile unsigned long *)x))
```

In my case mostly the usage will be like:

```
#define INTR_SRC(x) ADDR_VAL(INTR_BASE_VAL(x) + 0x180)

INTR_SRC(0) = 0x24ul;
```

Assuming that `INTR_BASE_VAL(x)` is a value calculated to `0x1A002D00`, do both of the above menioned `ADDR_VAL(x)` defines provide the same results for the `INTR_SRC` define?

Answer (score 3):

The first one will cast all `x` expression to `volatile unsigned long *` while the second one - only its first part.

For example, in first case, the whole `INTR_BASE_VAL(x) + 0x180` will be converted to `volatile unsigned long *` while in the second one - just `INTR_BASE_VAL(x)`.

---

First expression unrolled:

```
(*((volatile unsigned long *)(INTR_BASE_VAL(x) + 0x180)))
```

The whole expression gets casted and then dereferenced

Second expression unrolled:

```
(*((volatile unsigned long *)INTR_BASE_VAL(x) + 0x180))
```

Only the first part gets casted but the whole thing (`INTR_BASE_VAL(x)` casted to a pointer *plus* the value of `0x180`) is dereferenced.

Comment: So am I correct in saying in the second one the resultant value will be a dereferenced value of INTR_BASE_VAL(x) + 0x180*(sizeof(unsigned long)) while in the first one its equivalent to a dereferenced value of (INTR_BASE_VAL(x) + 0x180)

Comment: @Quest, please check my edits. I'm not quite sure where `sizeof(unsigned long)` comes from in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Given the usage

```
ADDR_VAL(INTR_BASE_VAL(x) + 0x180)
```

The first form will expand to

```
(*((volatile unsigned long *)(INTR_BASE_VAL(x) + 0x180)))
```

The expression `INTR_BASE_VAL(x) + 0x180` is cast to type `volatile unsigned long *` and then dereferenced.

The second form expands to

```
(*((volatile unsigned long *) INTR_BASE_VAL(x) + 0x180))
```

The expression `INTR_BASE_VAL(x)` is cast to type `volatile unsigned long *`, `0x180` is added to the result, and the result of the addition is dereferenced.

Does it make a difference?  Depends on what the type of `INTR_BASE_VAL(x)` winds up being.  Remember that pointer arithmetic is based on the type of the pointed-to object: `p + 1` will give a different address if `p` is a `char *` vs an `int *`.  So if `INTR_BASE_VAL(x)` evaluates to a type that's a different size than `unsigned long`, the two forms will give different results.

In this case, you should use the first form.